# What statistical analysis to use?

Tags: self-study, computational-statistics

What statistical analysis should I use if I have 2 groups of subjects (high and low comprehenders) which are divided into 3 subgroups according to text genre (poetry, short story, drama) and subjected into three reading tests (pre-, post-intervention and post-intervention with text familiarity)? I have six participants, one for each subgroup who each produced verbal reports of strategies for three texts (one genre). The dependent variable is the proportion of accurate verbal reports per text. My hypotheses are that a) genre b) condition (test) and c) reading proficiency will have a significant effect on the proportion of verbal reports.

Comment: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/topics/logistic.htm